# Accessing video framerate from WMP (10+) control in VB6

Tags: vb6, wmp

I have to use the noted combination of tools, so suggestions that amount to "don't do that" are not helpful (-:

I can find no reliable way to determine the framerate of a video loaded into a WMP control. Is there some known way to get this value? It's such a basic piece of info that I can't believe I'm not missing something.

In theory I can instance `IWMPMedia3` and set that to `[player].currentmedia` then ask for `.GetAttributeByType("framerate", "", 0)`, but apparently there is some state that the player/media must be in for that to work, and I can't determine when that state exists.

In the IDE, when I try to get the attribute it always fails with `Invalid procedure call or argument`. I open the debug window and test whether the correct objects are instantiated -- they are. Then I can continue and I have the correct framerate. Clearly that won't work in production. (-:

It's not just waiting that does the trick -- I must actually debug test for Nothing on the objects to get it to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the framerate item does not get initialized immediately after you set a source video to the control. I tried to wait and call DoEvents and at first found no reliable way to get it working. Displaying a message box and waiting 30 seconds sometimes did it, but not always.

I then decided to examine the attribute by code, and to my surprise, simply checking using getAttributeCountByType() seems to initialize the item without waiting a single millisecond.

In the following code, if the checkbox is enabled, which calls getAttributeCountByType(), the function always succeeds. I tried with AVI, MPEG and MP4 files and it worked on Windows 7. If the checkbox is not checked, it always fails with all types of video files:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Text1.Text
Dim media As IWMPMedia3
Set media = WindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia
If Check1.Value = vbChecked Then
   Label1.Caption = "media.getAttributeCountByType " & media.getAttributeCountByType("framerate", "")
End If
MsgBox "Frame Rate = " & media.getItemInfoByType("framerate", "", 0)
```

Comment: Great info, thanks. I never would have gotten there. BTW I think the step of using IWMPMedia3 may be redundant as the .currentmedia item seems to support that interface by default. Will test.

Comment: It isn't obvious, but .currentmedia does support IWPMedia3, at least in more recent versions of WMP. Getting the frame rate doesn't work for .FLV as far as I can tell (apparently it doesn't store it as metadata), but that's the only issue so far. Thanks again!

Comment: Most of my multimedia experience is not with WMP, so I just followed your lead about IWMPMedia3. And you're right about FLV because I tested with a file here and the framerate did not work. There is another solution that works with all 4 formats (and others). It's the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia) from the company I work for, but I didn't suggest it last time because you explicitly mentioned WMP control. You can try the free evaluation from the website if you like. And it works with VB6 if you must stick with it.